# What is the difference between %...!% and %...>%in R?

Tags: r

I want to understand difference between these two operations. Thank you in advance.

```
df %...!% (function(err){
  
}) %...>% {
  
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/reference/pipes.html)

Comment: Hi, when asking questions like this,  please reference the **package** to which the functions or operators belong.  That allows us to look at the help pages.  //   downvoted because reading the Man page should be the very first thing one does before going to SO